# How can we use .wsdl file from local drive to send soap request?

Tags: java

Below is my code and got the error "Protocal file not supposted in URL"

```
          SOAPConnectionFactory soapConnectionFactory =
              SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();
              SOAPConnection soapConnection =
              soapConnectionFactory.createConnection();

              // Send SOAP Message to SOAP Server
              URL url = new URL("file:C:/Users/sbsrvc_test/Desktop/Test1.wsdl");
              SOAPMessage soapResponse =
              soapConnection.call(createSOAPRequest(Payload), url);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
URL url = new File("file:C:/Users/sbsrvc_test/Desktop/Test1.wsdl").toURI().toURL();
```